# Tcl8.4 expr floating point always returns incorrect results

Tags: tcl

I am new to this forum and thanks for your help in advance!

Recently, I encountered an issue with tclsh script (v.8.4) where when I typed in "expr 1.0", I got "2.6996291800504495e-231".  Trying to see what I might have missed.  Is this due to compilation issues or something else that I might not have linked properly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more information than you've provided.  What were you expecting?

Comment: @James: He was obviously expecting `1.0`

Answer (score 0):

With Tcl 8.4, as with the currently supported versions, I would have expected `expr 1.0` to have given `1.0` as a result. Such tiny numbers as you describe are more likely to come from some operation that subtracted two *almost* equal numbers from each other. Such values sometimes come up in floating point arithmetic, mainly due to the fact that finite precision math always has values it cannot easily represent.

But why it's being produced when you ask for `expr 1.0`? That's a total mystery. Has something overridden the `expr` command? Is it something in your `~/.tclshrc`? By comparison, on one of my systems where I'm sure it isn't doing anything too strange:

```
bash$ tclsh8.4
% expr 1.0 
1.0
% info patchlevel
8.4.19
```